# flup/fastcgi cpu usage under no-load conditions

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, lighttpd, flup

I'm running Django as threaded fastcgi via flup, served by lighttpd, communicating via sockets.

What is the expected CPU usage for each fastcgi thread under no load? On startup, each thread runs at 3-4% cpu usage for a while, and then backs off to around .5% over the course of a couple of hours. It doesn't sink below this level.

Is this much CPU usage normal? Do I have some bug in my code that is causing the idle loop to require more processing than it should? I expected the process to use no measurable CPU when it was completely idle.

I'm not doing anything ridiculously complicated with Django, definitely nothing that should require extended processing. I realize that this isn't a lot of load, but if it's a bug I introduced, I would like to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked at this on django running as fastcgi on both Slicehost (django 1.1, python 2.6) and Dreamhost (django 1.0, python 2.5), and I can say this:

Running the `top` command shows the processes use a large amount of CPU to start up for ~2-3 seconds, then drop down to 0 almost immediately.

Running the `ps aux` command after starting the django app shows something similar to what you describe, **however** this is actually misleading. From the Ubuntu man pages for ps:

> CPU usage is currently expressed as
>   the percentage of time spent running
>   during the entire lifetime of a
>   process. This is not ideal, and it
>   does not conform to the standards that
>   ps otherwise conforms to. CPU usage is
>   unlikely to add up to exactly 100%.

Basically, the %CPU column shown by `ps` is actually an *average* over the time the process has been running. The decay you see is due to the high initial spike followed by inactivity being averaged over time.

Answer (score 0):

Your fast-cgi threads must not consume any (noticeable) CPU if there are no requests to process.

You should investigate the load you are describing. I use the same architecture and my threads are completely idle.